# I want to compare the current date of my server with a date stored in a mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, email, date

How can I compare the current date of the web server with a date I have stored in the mySQL database and 3 days before that that in the database to send a notification email ?

Comment: I want to send the email every month , 3 days before the day stored in the mySQL database

Comment: Do you store only the date part in your database, like the integer `28` and want to send emails on `25th` of each month?

Comment: I store the date like a date type of mySQL YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: I also store names and emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select rows whose `mydate` is at least `3` days earlier than the current date:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   mydate <= SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

Comment: And to automatically send the e-mail can I use a cron-job that executes the script every day ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write a program which queries the db and get all email ids which has *(now()-3) = field in db you are comparing against* and send mail to those email ids and add it as a scheduled task/crontab which will get executed daily(schedule time when web server is less utilized).

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentDate     =     date("Y-m-d");
$now = new DateTime($date_start);
$ref = new DateTime($currentDate);

if($now > $ref){
$diff = $now->diff($ref);
printf('%d days', $diff->d);}
else{echo"Expired";}
```